# Is it possible to consider a mechanism without adding noise to provide differential privacy?

Tags: data-privacy, differential-privacy

We have a set of secrets $S = \{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}$ known to an adversary. Each $x_i \in S$ belongs to user $u_i$ who needs to obfuscate his secret, i.e. $K(x_i) = o_i$, using the notion of $d-$privacy defined in the following.

We assume that we have a numeric function $d(x,x^{\prime})$,  giving the distinguishability level between $x,x^{\prime}$, which depends on our scenario and the privacy guarantees we wish to express. The corresponding notion of privacy is the requirement that for an arbitrary pair $x,x^{\prime}$, we have $K(x)(O) ≤ e^{ε.d(x,x^{\prime})} K(x^{\prime})(O)$.

Is it possible to define $K(x)$ as a function that, when given $x_i$ as input, randomly chooses an element from the set $S^{\prime}$ within the subset $S$, where the elements in $S^{\prime}$ are the neighbors of $x_i$ and the selection is uniform? I am wondering if $K(x)$ can be considered as a true mechanism, given that it does not use the notion of adding noise!

Does this function necessarily achieve the best utility, given that we add no noise? By utility, I mean minimizing the absolute distance between each $o_i$ and its corresponding $x_i$.